# Java - Read loosely structured data from file

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, file-io, filereader

I'm currently trying to learn how Java code behaves and treats input and output files. As much as I understand how to read content of the file line by line and put them into an array, I have a trouble understanding how to read certain values from the file that occur every n-number of lines and then put them into an array. 
For example, I have an input test file that looks like this:

```
2
Australia
John
42
Blue
USA
Jeremmy
15
Black
```

First line is a size of an array. The following lines are the content I want to read from the file and put inside the said array (in this example I've made it would be : country, name, age, eye colour). In other words, I want to read some objects properties that occur every four lines, so I can print them out later on when I choose, for example one of the people.
For now I'm stuck in here and don't know how to move forward since most people didn't try to operate on a file like this.

```
   private static String[] readPeople(File file) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String sizeText = br.readLine();
        int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeText);
        String[] peopleSet= new String[size];

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                String peopleInfo= br.readLine();
                peopleSet[i] = peopleInfo;
            }
        }
        return peopleSet;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a list instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to make the lines colon delimited

Have you entries be colon delimited between values in the file:

```
Australia:John:42:Blue
USA:Jeremmy:15:Black
```

Then in your file parser:

```
private static List<Person> readPeople(File file) {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
      String line = "";
      while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] args = line.split(":");
        String country = args[0];
        String name = args[1];
        int age = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        String eyeColor = args[3];

        Person p = new Person(name, country, age, eyeColor);
        people.add(p);
      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.err.println(ex);
    } 
    return people;
}
```

Finally define the Person class

```
class Person {
   String name;
   String country;
   int age;
   String eyeColor;

   public Person(String name, String country, int age, String eyeColor) {
      this.name = name;
      this.country = country;
      this.age = age;
      this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
     return String.format("%s:%s:%d:%s", country, name, age, eyeColor);
   }
}
```

Add your error checks and getters/setters as needed

This will return the list of people as defined in your file and you can check the size of the list by calling `.size()` on the return list object.

**Update**

Added `toString()` override to create the colon separate entries for when it is to be written out to either file or console

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I offer you this code.

```
    File Read_File = new File("file_path"); 

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Read_File));
        String line;
        int line_number = 0;

        int size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());



        for (int try_ = 0; try_ < size; try_++) {
            String read = br.readLine();
            for(int try_four = 0; try_four<4; try_four++) {
                //save input operation
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null)
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
    }
```

but using list is best way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code only reads from the file when the condition is true. It doesn't matter how many times you go around the loop, the *file content* only advances when you actually read with `br.readLine()`.

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        String peopleInfo= br.readLine();
        peopleSet[i] = peopleInfo;
    }
}
```

It's also not clear which lines you want to read. This code will loop `size` times (2) but only read a line every other time, thus it will only read "Australia."

If you want to read the people's names ("John" and "Jeremmy"), which are the third lines in each group of four, you could do this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (j % 4 != 2) {
            people[i] = line;
        }
    }
}
```

This reads all eight lines (from "Australia" to "Black"). For each person, the values of `j` will go from `0` to `3`; the third line thus is when `j % 4 == 2`.

It will store the names into array `people` which is of length 2. I renamed it from `peopleSet` because it's not a Java `Set`. The original name is misleading.